# React-Bootstrap: multiple active keys on navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I want to make a navbar which has multiple active keys. 
Below is code for navbar.

```
<Nav bsStyle="pills" activeKey={1} onSelect={handleSelect}>
  <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/home">NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Item">NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
  <NavItem eventKey={3} disabled>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

Can i put activeKey Prop as an array ??

For e.g:- activeKey=[1,2,3]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *"a navbar which has multiple keys"*? Do you want several NavItem to be active at the same time?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention "active keys" . I have edited the answer accordingly.
Can u suggest how do implement multiple active keys ??? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there doesn't appear to be a way to do assign an array for `activeKey` for `<Nav>`; it only takes one value. However other elements seem to support this, such as `<Tabs>`. Not sure why this is.

---

#### Solution

You can still accomplish what you want though, with some slight modification. The solution does not use `activeKey` and `eventKey` at all. Instead, we use an array, and for each of the `<NavItem>`'s we check if that index exists in the array; if it does, we give it the `active` prop.

Have a look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qjpnm84/).

---

Here's a snippet of that fiddle. Here, `activeKeys` is an array which can contain 1, 2, 3 or any combination of those.

```
<Nav bsStyle="pills">
  <NavItem active={activeKeys.indexOf(1) >= 0 ? true : false}>NavItem 1 content</NavItem>
  <NavItem active={activeKeys.indexOf(2) >= 0 ? true : false}>NavItem 2 content</NavItem>
  <NavItem active={activeKeys.indexOf(3) >= 0 ? true : false}>NavItem 3 content</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

---

The [**official docs**](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs-props-navitem) show that `<NavItem>` can take an `active` prop:

> **active** | type: *boolean* | default: *false*